# What should I expect from floor when binary rounding close to integers?

Tags: c++, numerical-methods

When I am writing code and using `floor` on the mathematical expressions which are likely to be almost an integer number, I feel worried about the results. Especially, since numbers are converted in base 2 in the memory, I am always feeling that there is a chance the code gives me `(n-1)` when I expect `n`. Is there such mechanism in `floor` to prevent such numerical errors?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::floor((10 - 8.3) * 10) << std::endl;   // 16
    std::cout << std::floor(100 - 83) << std::endl;          // 17
    return 0;
}
// Acknowledgement: thanks to user Ryan
```

[ideone test](https://ideone.com/rdj945)

Comment: `floor` should fine to trust. The question is whether the number you're flooring is really what you're expecting it to be, not whether `floor` will get things wrong.

Comment: @user2357112, fixed the title.

Comment: You should expect `floor` to floor. It's not going to look at `0.99999999999999989` and say "oh, that's so close, let's just round it up".

Comment: @user2357112, But how did it give me `1` for `0.999999999999999999999999999999999l` ?

Comment: Yes, what you’re worried about is a possibility: https://ideone.com/rdj945

Comment: `0.999999999999999999999999999999999l` is `1.0l`. It's not `floor` doing that.

Comment: Or, to call back to my previous comment, the number you're flooring isn't what you were expecting it to be. `floor` didn't get things wrong.

Comment: There's a limit to how much precision you can get out of a float and I think you've exceeded it. That gets rounded up during the compile phase, not when calling `floor`. Try with different `9` counts and see where the threshold is.

Comment: @jeremine simple: 0.999999999999999999999999999999999l rounded to two decimal places is 1.00.

Comment: @rsp, As a side note, the number `0.(9)` in fact _is the same number_ as `1`. It's not rounding, it's math https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...

Comment: Anyway, you can add according to how many digits of precision you have: `std::floor(expr + 0.000001)`

Comment: The first question to ask yourself is *why* your are taking the floor.